# Who is Leta Lestrange?

Tags: character, fantastic-beasts, fantastic-beasts-where-to-find-them

In *Fantastic Beasts And Where To Find Them*, I am curious to know who **Leta Lestrange** is, other than that she is the girlfriend of Newt. Whenever I hear Lestrange, Bellatrix Lestrange hits mind first.

1. Is she evil or good?
2. Was she a reason why Newt was expelled from Hogwarts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Leta Lestrange** was a witch who, sometime between `1908 to 1916`, had a `close relationship` with `Newton Scamander` while they were both students at **Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry**, due to their outcast nature and love of studying magical creatures. One of Leta's experiments went wrong, endangering the life of another student. Rather than see his friend expelled, `Newt` took the blame and was expelled in her place. This left him bitter, but still much in love with Leta.

Reference from Wiki : http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Leta_Lestrange

Comment: To quote the wiki further: "director David Yates, we will learn more about Leta Lestrange, and Newt's relationship with her, in future movies in the franchise"
We don't know enough about her to state if she's evil or good (also, is it ever so black and white?). The fact that she's from the Lestrange family already makes the character intriguing, but it still could go both ways. I suspect her character to have enough depth to at least make the answer to the good or evil question a complicated one.

Comment: @ThomasMulder Feel free to add that as an answer.

Comment: Was that really Answer-worthy? I felt like it added merit to Ironman's answer more :-)